# Can't get the content through rvest

Tags: html, r, rvest

[target site](http://mall.autohome.com.cn/finance/detail/163530-999999-0.html)

I want to get the detail information for the cars, so I've tried the code below,

```
url <- "http://mall.autohome.com.cn/finance/detail/163530-999999-0.html"

web <- read_html(url, encoding = "utf-8")
web %>% html_nodes("#detailParameterData > div.detail-cs-grid > table") %>%extract2(1)
```

however, I don't even know what's the result was. Class = xml_nodeset, I don't even know how to open it.

I need all the detail information in the blue area:

[image]

Comment: Since you need JavaScript to load the second tab, you'll need RSelenium.

Comment: Then look into `html_table` and/or `html_text` instead of extract2.

Comment: @alistaire thanks， which function exactly?

Comment: Quite a few of them. RSelenium drives an actual browser from R, so you'll need to start the browser session and get it to click on the tab so you can scrape with rvest. The design is a little more object-oriented than usual for R, but [the documentation is decent](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html). If you use it with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), the basics are doable, if not transparent.